# Curl Request to Axios Request how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, axios

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token=sfg999666t673t7t82" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"phone_call": { "call_direction": true, "targetable_type": "contact", "targetable": { "id": "1", "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Sampleton (sample)", "work_number ":"5304915427", "mobile_number ":"11919457004 " }, "note ": { "description": "Sample note"} }}' -X POST https://domain.myfreshworks.com/crm/sales/api/phone_calls
```

When ı do this request ı succesfully get the response, but ı just want to same request with axios. How can I do that ?
I try this but not works ı get'a cors error.

```
 const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Token sfg999666t673t7t82',
    };
    var dataString =
      '{"phone_call": { "call_direction": true, "targetable_type": "contact", "targetable": { "id": "1", "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Sampleton (sample)", "work_number ":"5304915427", "mobile_number ":"11919457004 " }, "note ": { "description": "Sample note"} }}';

    Axios.post('https://domain.myfreshworks.com/crm/sales/api/phone_calls', dataString, {
      headers: headers,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

``
```

Comment: You can not enable CORS from your end, whoever is in charge of `domain.myfreshworks.com` would have to do this. If that is not an option, then your only alternative to get this data via client-side requests, would be to use a _CORS proxy_.

Comment: But when ı curl request ı dont get'a cors error.

Comment: Of course, CORS only applies to client-side requests made by a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The headers seem incorrect in your `axios` version.

`Authorization: Token token=sfg999666t673t7t82` is not the same as `Authorization: 'Token sfg999666t673t7t82'`.

Try changing `Authorization: 'Token sfg999666t673t7t82'` to `Authorization: 'Token token=sfg999666t673t7t82'` so that the requests are equivalent.

Comment: I changed like this, but also ı am getting cors error.

Comment: As CBroe says, The server still needs enable CORS. I was assuming the token had some role to play but apparently not.